# Converting bytes to array of int16

Tags: arrays, vb.net, type-conversion

I want to convert data in Bytes from TCP to an array of Int16, but variable value gets a value of 8 Bytes.

```
        Dim dataImageShort(nBytes) As Short
        Dim value() As Byte
        For i = 0 To nBytes-1
            value = dataImageByte.Skip(2 * i).Take(2).ToArray
            dataImageShort(i) = BitConverter.ToInt16(value, 0)
        Next
```

Comment: Your loop should be '`For i = 0 To nBytes - 1`

Answer (score 0):

There's a .Net API for that.

It takes a byte array and returns a 16 bit int.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: This function only takes 2 Bytes at a time, I want all the bytes in the array to be converted. The loop takes too much proces time..